# html listbox and submit to php page

Tags: php, html, html-lists, html-select

I create a list like this

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 120px;" id="list" name="keywordlist" size="0">                
</select>
```

and I add item to this by jquery and every thing work ok until I submit it to the server(PHP) the post variable contain only the last `<option></option>` I clicked on I want to get all the list from the server side.

this the jquery:

```
 $("#list").append("<option value='"+$("#keyword").val()+"' selected='true'>"+$("#keyword").val()+"</option>");
                var i= $("#list").attr("size");
                i=parseInt(i);
                i++;
                $("#list").attr("size",i);
```

Comment: Show us the jquery code building it, and the PHP code accessing the submission data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use select name `keywordlist[]` instead of `keywordlist`